# How can I see where exactly exception occurred in Android Studio?

Tags: android, debugging, exception, android-studio, stack-trace

With Eclipse, stack trace was printed out in Logcat so I could trace where exactly in my application the exception occurred. However, with Android Studio the exception gets neatly parsed in a window but I cannot find the source line and file.

I tried exploring "stackState" (see below) but didn't find any clue.

How are you supposed to find it?

[image]

Comment: In Android Studio, it is even better, you can double click on file name in Logcat and it can be opened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LogCat` in `Android Studio` will show the same info as `Eclipse`

You can show the window with: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> in Mac.

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> enable "View Breakpoints..."
and check if inside if the option: "`Java Exception Breakpoints`" is disabled!
[image]

Read the documents from the official documentation:

[**Reading and writing Logs**](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)

[**Debugging with Android Studio**](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html)

Answer (score 0):

> With Eclipse, stack trace was printed out in Logcat so I could trace where exactly in my application the exception occurred.

It does that too, in Android Studio, in the Android Monitor view (docked on the bottom of your screen).

> However, with Android Studio the exception gets neatly parsed in a window but I cannot find the source line and file.

I suspect that's because you have Android Studio's debugger set up to break on exceptions. I haven't used that, but if it works the way Eclipse's equivalent feature worked, the exception will not show up in LogCat, because it hasn't gotten there yet, courtesy of the debugger.